# expression map/set iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++, iterator

I am trying to make an iterator from a custom class that I had made so that I can see if there is already a "tagName" inside a vector of classes which is inside structure PLC:

```
vector<plcClass>::iterator plcIndex = find_plcClass(_plcList->begin(), _plcList->end(), "tagName");

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION find
        template<class InputIterator, class T>
             InputIterator find_plcClass (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)
        {
          while (first!=last) {
            if ( (*first).PLC.tagName == val) return first;
            ++first;
          }
          return last;
        }
```

Where the Class is:

```
    #ifndef PLC_H
#define PLC_H

#include "Pyramid.h"

class plcClass
{
public:

    // structures

    struct parent_t{
        string tagName;
        string rack;
        string slot;
        vector<string> address;
        vector<string> term;
        vector<string> termDesc;
        vector<string> descA;
        vector<string> descB;
        vector<string> descC;
    }PLC;

    // constructors
    plcClass();
    //parent found first
    plcClass( string , string , string , string, string , string , string );
    // de-constructor
    ~plcClass();

};

#endif
```

I had this working for a different class but it just seems to crash upon entering find_plcClass

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong (at least nothing to cause a crash)... are you sure the problem is in this portion of code? Is there memory corruption going on elsewhere?

Comment: Yea I am pretty sure the issue is only right there

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see anything to cause a crash. The only thing that strikes me as seriously odd is using a 2nd template parameter `T` for your search value, since `PLC.tagName` is statically defined as a `string`, so the template could never be instantiated with `T` anything other than a `string`. Certainly not the problem you're looking for.

Comment: @dvnrrs in this case the template should instantiate with `T` as `char *` or `char[8]` not `string`, but I don't see anything wrong either.

Comment: @MarkRansom That's true, didn't think of that. Of course those would automatically convert to `string`s anyway if that were the static type of the function argument, but... yeah.

Comment: yeah all of you guys are correct.  The issue was something I simplified to "tagName" because it would have required me to add a lot more information.  It all boiled down to me using the wrong enumerator.  Thanks for the help guys!